# Quadratic programming problem

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to solve a (Sequence) Quadratic Programming (SQP) problem in *Mathematica*.

Here’s the problem setup:

```
size = 9; (* for illustrative purposes, can be larger *)
(* known coefficients *)
m1 = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, j, k, l}};
m2 = {{m, 0, 0, 0}, {0, n, 0, 0}, {0, 0, o, 0}};
(* unknowns *)
θ = Table[{Subscript[x, i], Subscript[y, i], Subscript[z, i], 1}, {i, size}];

(* My system of quadratic equations *)
data == Transpose [m1.Transpose[θ] + m2.Transpose[θ^2]];

(*Subject to the following constraints *)
constraints = 
  Table[{Subscript[x, i]^2 + Subscript[y, i]^2 + Subscript[z, i]^2 == 1}, {i, size}];
```

Sample data:

```
data =  
  {{0.0326857, -0.23977, -0.980886}, {-0.00491715, 0.160488, -0.980237},
   {-0.0189063, 0.137756, 0.969873}, {-0.0165821, -0.256267, 0.967219}, 
   {-0.00898421, -1.00759, -0.258025}, {-0.0131764, 0.918642, 0.192466}, 
   {-0.00673595, 0.0658302, -0.996648}, {0.00647973, -0.147268, -0.997363}, 
   {-0.0200075, -0.164866, 0.981011}, {-0.0242359,0.0523168, 0.981269}, 
   {-0.0132569, -1.03757, -0.0196142}, {-0.0164502, 0.94126, -0.0110496}, 
   {-1.01661, -0.0493139, -0.0169287}, {-0.0250339, -0.0569752, 0.988069}, 
   {0.981252, -0.048789, -0.00833748}, {-0.00965323,-0.0403172, -1.00421}};

m1 = 
  {{0.851943, 0, 0, 0.0154734}, {0.500424, 1.01131, 0, 0.0564313}, 
   {-0.164399, 0.00390119, 1.00309, 0.00583693}};

m2 = {{0.00912, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -0.00320, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.00175, 0}};
```

Comment: Added some sample data to help...

Comment: What is your objective function? What you have above is a matrix, not a function. As written, it will give a recursion error, but that's a different matter: should not reuse `f` in defining it since `f` is an element of `m2`.

Comment: Daniel, I have a set of quadratic equations given by  data == Transpose [m1.Transpose[θ] + m2.Transpose[θ^2]];

Comment: Edited the original question (f is not re-used any more).

Comment: @Daniel: There is not a single objective function but a set of equations subject to a set of constraints...

Comment: I think you might want `size=16`. To make the domensions compatible in the `data == ...` equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your problem we can try matrix norm minimization. One straight forward way will be to use `FindMinimum` as follows

```
size = 16;
θ =Transpose[(Array[#, size] & /@ {x, y, z})~Join~{ConstantArray[1, size]}];
cons = Flatten[θ /. {a_, b_, c_,1} -> {a^2 + b^2 + c^2 == 1}] /. List :> And;
res = FindMinimum[{
        Norm[Transpose[m1.Transpose[θ] +m2.Transpose[[Theta]^2]]-data,"Frobenius"],
        cons},
        Transpose[{Flatten@(θ[[All, 1 ;; 3]]),RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3 size]}]
   ];
```

The local minimum is not too bad

```
First@res
```

> 0.374061

do a recheck as

```
ob=Transpose[m1.Transpose[θ]+m2.Transpose[θ^2]]-data;
Norm[ob/.res[[2]],"Frobenius"]
```

> 0.374061

Now we can see that constraints are fulfilled with a good tolerance

```
conResolve = (θ /. res[[2]] /. {a_, b_, c_, 1} -> a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 1);
{Mean@conResolve, Variance@conResolve}
```

> {3.38641*10^-13,1.26468*10^-24}

With a random assignment of solution your given objective tend to behave like the following

```
LaunchKernels[10];
SeedRandom[1234];
check = BlockRandom[
vals = ParallelTable[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 2], {10^5}];
ParallelMap[(Flatten[{#,Norm[ob /. (Transpose[{Flatten@(θ[[All, 1 ;; 3]]), 
            RandomReal[Sort@#, 3 size]}] /. {a_, b_} :> Rule[a, b]),"Frobenius"]
                     }] &) /@ # &, Partition[vals, 10^4]]];
```

The minimum value of the objective I could get with these random solution assignment from different random sub-intervals of $[-10,10]$.

```
Last@First@SortBy[Flatten[check, 1], Last]
```

> 3.80535

is pretty bad compared to what `FindMinimum` gave us out of the box.

You can see the acceptable trend for the occurrence of a local minimum which looks like a global one for the considered interval! This is bad and can stall any optimization algorithm.
[image]

Comment: Brilliant. This is more than I needed.

Comment: Kudos to Daniel as well for figuring out that f was an element of m2 and I was repeating a variable in two instances.

Answer (score 6):

Correcting a few things, it can be set up as follows.

```
size = 16;
\[Theta] = 
  Table[{Subscript[x, i], Subscript[y, i], Subscript[z, i], 1}, {i, 
    size}];
constraints = 
  Table[{Subscript[x, i]^2 + Subscript[y, i]^2 + Subscript[z, i]^2 == 
     1}, {i, size}];

data = {{0.0326857, -0.23977, -0.980886}, {-0.00491715, 
    0.160488, -0.980237}, {-0.0189063, 0.137756, 
    0.969873}, {-0.0165821, -0.256267, 
    0.967219}, {-0.00898421, -1.00759, -0.258025}, {-0.0131764, 
    0.918642, 0.192466}, {-0.00673595, 
    0.0658302, -0.996648}, {0.00647973, -0.147268, -0.997363}, \
{-0.0200075, -0.164866, 0.981011}, {-0.0242359, 0.0523168, 
    0.981269}, {-0.0132569, -1.03757, -0.0196142}, {-0.0164502, 
    0.94126, -0.0110496}, {-1.01661, -0.0493139, -0.0169287}, \
{-0.0250339, -0.0569752, 
    0.988069}, {0.981252, -0.048789, -0.00833748}, {-0.00965323, \
-0.0403172, -1.00421}};

m1 = {{0.851943, 0, 0, 0.0154734}, {0.500424, 1.01131, 0, 
    0.0564313}, {-0.164399, 0.00390119, 1.00309, 0.00583693}};

m2 = {{0.00912, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -0.00320, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.00175, 0}};
```

Now define the polynomials we want to approximately satisfy.

```
polys = data - 
   Transpose[m1.Transpose[\[Theta]] + m2.Transpose[\[Theta]^2]];

fpolys = Flatten[polys];
```

To optimize, we could minimize the sum of squares of fpolys. I do that below.
Unfortunately this is no longer a quadratic objective function, but it is still amenable to e.g. nonlinear interior point methods (the presence of constraints rule out some other approaches).

```
{min, vals} = FindMinimum[{fpolys.fpolys, Flatten[constraints]}, 
 Evaluate[Sequence @@ Variables[polys]]]

(* Out[16]= {0.139921, {Subscript[x, 1] -> 0.0199536, 
  Subscript[x, 2] -> -0.0251878, Subscript[x, 3] -> -0.0358971, 
  Subscript[x, 4] -> -0.0362198, Subscript[x, 5] -> -0.0588463, 
  Subscript[x, 6] -> -0.0943821, Subscript[x, 7] -> -0.0244723, 
  Subscript[x, 8] -> -0.00827959, Subscript[x, 9] -> -0.0374074, 
  Subscript[x, 10] -> -0.0409569, Subscript[x, 11] -> -0.063582, 
  Subscript[x, 12] -> -0.0958467, Subscript[x, 13] -> -0.939709, 
  Subscript[x, 14] -> -0.0419559, Subscript[x, 15] -> 0.878312, 
  Subscript[x, 16] -> -0.0260752, Subscript[y, 1] -> -0.294872, 
  Subscript[y, 2] -> 0.115827, Subscript[y, 3] -> 0.102224, 
  Subscript[y, 4] -> -0.292127, Subscript[y, 5] -> -0.965338, 
  Subscript[y, 6] -> 0.978937, Subscript[y, 7] -> 0.0212626, 
  Subscript[y, 8] -> -0.193187, Subscript[y, 9] -> -0.202956, 
  Subscript[y, 10] -> 0.0166422, Subscript[y, 11] -> -0.997514, 
  Subscript[y, 12] -> 0.994625, Subscript[y, 13] -> 0.306808, 
  Subscript[y, 14] -> -0.0936467, Subscript[y, 15] -> -0.464459, 
  Subscript[y, 16] -> -0.0814992, Subscript[z, 1] -> -0.955328, 
  Subscript[z, 2] -> -0.99295, Subscript[z, 3] -> 0.994114, 
  Subscript[z, 4] -> 0.955693, Subscript[z, 5] -> -0.254284, 
  Subscript[z, 6] -> 0.181039, Subscript[z, 7] -> -0.999474, 
  Subscript[z, 8] -> -0.981127, Subscript[z, 9] -> 0.978473, 
  Subscript[z, 10] -> 0.999022, Subscript[z, 11] -> -0.0303692, 
  Subscript[z, 12] -> -0.0391635, Subscript[z, 13] -> -0.151046, 
  Subscript[z, 14] -> 0.994721, Subscript[z, 15] -> 0.113338, 
  Subscript[z, 16] -> -0.996332}} *)
```

Sanity check on those constraints:

```
Max[Abs[Apply[Subtract, Flatten[constraints], {1}] /. vals]]

(* Out[19]= 7.30056*10^-7 *)
```

One can do better by setting `AccuracyGoal->12` in the `FindMinimum[...]`. If I do that, the max constraint violation drops to around 10^(-16), minimum staying about the same, at least to all printed digits.

Comment: Off topic but hope you agree MMA is not really updating its optimization capabilities over the last 5-8 years or even more and falling seriously behind as a multipurpose optimization suite. The breakthroughs in algorithms and new class of problems are hardly tractable (e.g using SuperFunctions like `FindMinimum` ) out of the box. SQP is one such major example. Anything interesting to expect in this direction of making `FindMinimum` more powerful and compatible to new age demands...?

Comment: Offtopic: Agree. Even some of the third party optimization suites like KNITRO are no longer making Mathematica versions...